# R: Split character vector of length n>1, at specific character, into a list of n vectors

Tags: regex, r, vector

I have a vector with repeating characters, and I need to break it at the positions where character is "" (empty character), thus getting a list of as many character vectors as 
my separator points. Vector t describes the situation now, while S is the result as it should be. I understand that using "" as separator could be a problem. In that case I could substitute it with a special character.

```
set.seed<-123
S<-list(character(10))
t<-as.vector(NULL)
for (i in 1:10) {
  temp<-c("",rep("a",rbinom(1,10,0.5)), rep("b", rbinom(1,10,0.5)), rep("c", rbinom(1,10,0.5)))
  t<-append(t,temp)
  S[[i]]<-temp[temp!=""]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably better ways but this seems to get close to what you want

```
trythis <- split(t, cumsum(t == ""))
```

***Added***

You edited the question to remove the blanks from `S`.  You could adapt my answer to

```
blanks  <- which(t == "")
trythis <- split(t[-blanks], cumsum(t == "")[-blanks])
```